# Local Crime Data (Drug) for Property Buying or Leasing

Tags: real-estate, rental-property, historical-data, online-data-source

Folks,

I am looking for online data sources that have historical data on crime incidents.

I have looked at a few sources simply by googling:

- crimemapping.com
- local police department - incident reports
- state-level crime data

I think Redfin and realtor.com dropped neighborhood crime data from their websites.

The crime data I look for is mostly drug-related data.

I suppose if you have kids and consider moving to a new neighborhood, you would also check this type of crime data.

What are your main data sources and any suggestions (other than city or county-level police department incident reports)?

I wonder if there is a walk score version for drugs?

Comment: Now that I've answered this Q, I'm not sure it's actually personal finance related, but I'll leave my answer up anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

You don't give a jurisdiction, but based on "state-level" and your spelling of "neighborhood," I will assume United States and have tagged this answer thusly.

The [Uniform Crime Reporting Program](https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/ucr) is a program of the Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI):

> The Uniform Crime Reporting (UCR) Program generates reliable statistics for use in law enforcement. It also provides information for students of criminal justice, researchers, the media, and the public. The program has been providing crime statistics since 1930.

For historical crime information, you can visit UCR's [Publications](https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/ucr/publications) page.

For recent crime information, you can use the [Crime Data Explorer](https://crime-data-explorer.app.cloud.gov/pages/home), which allows you to explore by state, agency (e.g. city police department), and year. Once there, you can slice and dice by demographics.

For detailed information, there is the [Lexis/Nexis Community Crime Map](https://communitycrimemap.com/), where you can navigate to specific addresses, neighborhoods, or ZIP codes. Hover over a crime dot to see details of a specific reported crime, e.g.:

> #09512345-Burglary - Commercial
> Report Number:  09512345
> Crime:  Burglary, Breaking And Entering
> Location Type:  Residence, Home (Includes Apartment)
> Date:   07/18/2022
> Time:   12:00 pm
> Accuracy:   Address
> Address of Crime:   7XX 799 SOME MAIN ST, 01234
> Agency: Your Town Police Department

If you click the Filter button, you'll see that you can filter by type of offense. One of the choices is **Drugs / Narcotics Violation**.